# asp.net mvc 4.5: getting HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem to work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to finish some lightweight tasks *after* a controller has finished his work and I use `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem()` for this.

I'm seeing a strange behavior, so I make an artificial proof-of-concept app for this.

in my `global.asax.cs` I have this nice function:

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    private static NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public static void ContinueWorkOnBackground(Task workItem)
    {
        workItem.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.IsFaulted)
            {
                var ex = t.Exception;
                logger.Error(ex);
            }
        });
        HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(_ => workItem);
    }
```

And in my controller I create a workitem and throw there:

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    logger.Info("About");
    ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
    MvcApplication.ContinueWorkOnBackground(TestWorkItem());
    return View();
}

private async Task TestWorkItem()
{
    logger.Trace("TestWorkItem");
    await Task.Delay(500);
    logger.Trace("let's fail");
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

I see the message "TestWorkItem" in logs, but never "let's fail" and no message on error.

I also did `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem((Func<CancellationToken,Task>)(_ => workItem));` to make sure the call is not ambiguous.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is the NLog lifetime tied to the request in any way? On a side note, it's best to not use `ContinueWith` when `await` is available.

Comment: NLog is there. I can open home page and see it appending to logs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that `TestWorkItem` is capturing the current request context, and attempting to resume on that request context after its `await`. (I explain [how this capture/resume works](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) on my blog). Since the request has completed, the request context no longer exists by the time it attempts to resume.

The best fix for this is to allow `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` to execute the code outside of a request context. So, first change your helper method to take a `Func<Task>` instead of a `Task`:

```
public static void ContinueWorkOnBackground(Func<Task> workItem)
{
  HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async _ =>
  {
    try
    {
      await workItem();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      logger.Error(ex);
    }
  });
}
```

Then you can call it as such:

```
public ActionResult About()
{
  logger.Info("About");
  ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
  MvcApplication.ContinueWorkOnBackground(() => TestWorkItem());
  return View();
}
```

Comment: Indeed. I understood it right away after reading about the capturing of context (yet failed to get that hours before as I was playing with the code). Thanks.