# Asynchronous call from Application_Error()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to figure out how to create an asynchronous call from Application_Error Method in MVC.

I have an e-mail dll that I have written which sends out an e-mail via asynchronous call using Smtp Client.

The problem is that when I call SendEmail method in my dll I have conflict of needing to await for the call.  Now if I try something like this:

```
protected async void Application_Error()
{
    var await emailService.SendEmail("Hello World");
}
```

It will not work, the method will never even be called.

Is there a way for me to make an asynchronous call from a synchronous method?  My research online hinted at `HttpServerUtility.TransferRequest` possibly being the answer but I could not figure out how to make it work with my request, it just doesn't make sense to me at the moment.

Comment: You can start background task and do all your needed actions in this task.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why is a sync call not enough here?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev what does the code looks like for something like that?

Comment: @usr I am sending an e-mail with SmtpClient which calls a method `Client.SendMailAsync(myMessage);` in my dll

Comment: Why are you not making a synchronous call?

Comment: @usr limitation of the dll, i cannot change it.

Comment: The reason is that web page context is gone on async interrupt. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34418901/58768

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> limitation of the dll, i cannot change it.

I don't know why that async call does not send an email. It should. There's a bug somewhere.

But a workaround is:

```
Task.Run(async () => { await emailService.SendEmail("Hello World"); }).Wait();
```

You could simplify and optimize this but this is the simplest way to bring the idea across. This pattern is always a safe way to synchronously call an async method. Not good for perf, but does not matter here because sending an email is 1000x more expensive than the overhead.

If you want to keep the async behavior you could remove the `Wait`. Although at that point I wonder why sending is not working in the first place. Is the bug triggered by the async behavior or is it always there?!

Comment: I think you missunderstand, the reason why it does not send the email is because if you put await with Application_Error() method, that method will no longer kick in when an error on the application happens, it only kicks in if it is a synchronous call.

Comment: Are you saying the presence of an `await` inside of Application_Error causes Application_Error to not be called? That can't be true because the caller does not *know* there is an await.

Comment: You can try `emailService.SendEmail("Hello World").Wait();`, too.

Comment: no, the presence of async in the method name `protected async void Application_Error()` cause it not to be called, as such I have to use `protected void Application_Error()` and in this case I cannot call await, so your example above cannot work.

Comment: would your last comment cause a deadlock?  That is what I am trying to avoid the most, even if it sacrifices a bit of performance.

Comment: The presence of async in the method "line" is untedectable by the caller. It cannot be true that this causes the method to not be called. But anyway, the await in my code is not in Application_Error. It's in the lambda body and it can be placed there. Although I forget an `async` but that was easy to add.

Comment: The Task.Run safely avoids the deadlock. If there's a deadlock without that depends on what emailService.SendEmail does. I'd go for the safer Task.Run.

Comment: Ok I have run it with the following code and it works: `Task.Run(() => { emailService.SendEmail("Hello World"); }).Wait();`  Can you re-assure me that this will not cause a deadlock?  And thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you should look to understand why these typical deadlocks arise. That's important to know and it will answer your question. There are good explanations on the web. Here, there's no deadlock because the lambda body runs with a null sync context. That's the whole point of the Task.Run.

Answer (score 4):

For those that may encounter this issue in the future, here is another solution that may be a bit more robust.  Instead of using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()` you can use `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem()`.  Doing things this way, asks the server to make a bit more of an effort to complete these tasks before shutting down.

Here's an example from a recent project:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
    HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct =>
        ExceptionLogger.LogAsync(ex));
}
```